# user created by shell script is not executing proceeding commands

Tags: shell

I have created a shell script as follows.

> username='root'
>   sudo -H -u "$username" bash 2<&0 << 'END_COMMAND'
>   useradd -m -s /bin/bash suhail
>   passwd suhail
>   mkdir ~/test
>   END_COMMAND

But i am getting the out put as follows when i trying to run this script file

> user@uvais-desktop:~/ssp$ ./test
>   sudo: unable to resolve host uvais-desktop
>   Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: Sorry, passwords do not match
>   passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
>   passwd: password unchanged

It is not prompting for password for the new user.Everything happened in a second. !!
Please help me if anyone could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you can't run passwd. It asks to write password twice which you can't do in the script. So you enter password once then for the second time you enter `mkdir ~test`, hence the message "Sorry, passwords do not match"

Instead of passwd suhail try:

```
echo suhail| passwd $username --stdin
```

Comment: Now it says unrecognized option '--stdin' :(

Comment: Does this need to be hard coded or will a user drive the username and password? In other words will this work? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html - see the sample script section.